# Clustering Infinispan DefaultCache with RemoteCache

Tags: cluster-computing, infinispan

I am currently using  TomcatInfinispanSessionManager. I have two machines, both are configured with TomcatInfinispanSessionManager,  forming a cluster. When a request comes to 1st Machine, a SessionID entry is placed in its ISPN cache. The same ISPN cache entry is placed in the 2nd Machine also.

Suppose if Machine 1 goes down, the session data is retrieved from the 2nd Machine’s ISPN cache. Till this moment, everything is working fine.

Now my requirement is that:- Now there is another ISPN server running in machine 3. I want to place this 3rd Machine also inside the cluster, thereby reading the session data from the 3rd ISPN cache. Is it possible? If yes, how to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure I understand your question, but just starting up a new tomcat instance and starting the Infinispan cache manager and the named cache where the session is stored should work. When it starts, it would find the other nodes, do state transfer, if needed, to rebalance the data, and you should be able to read data in the session from any node.

Comment: Hi Galder thank you very much for your reply. What i meant to say is 1st and 2nd machine has tomcat+ispn(tomacatinfinispansessionmanager) and the cache is being created using DefaultCacheManager. But the 3rd machine is having ispn server alone and the ispn server has been started in hotrod mode. Is is possible to form a cluster with these 3 ispn(2 default+1 remote).

Comment: Hmmm, that won't work unless you enable interoperability between embedded and remote access. This is available in latest Infinispan 5.3 release: https://docs.jboss.org/author/x/kYH2Aw

Answer (score 0):

Remote and embedded caches can only be mixed up when [interoperability/compatibility mode](https://docs.jboss.org/author/x/kYH2Aw) is enabled.